# Disable Keyboard Entry to ASP Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a text box with an ajaxToolkit:calendarextender attached to it.
I also have an `OnTextChanged="do something"` with an `AutoPostBack=true`.

**I only want my user to be able to enter data into a textbox by using the calendar extender.**

*I've tried setting the `readonly` property on the textbox to true. This works only if there is existing text in the textbox (if I `textbox.text = "such and such"` then entry via the calendar extender works).*

If I try selecting a date by clicking the textbox and selecting a date in the calendar extender, anything that is entered is immediately cleared because of the `autopostback` and the `OnTextChanged` event. I get this exception:

```
Exception was thrown at line 3169, column 13 in http://localhost:44994/ScriptResource.axd?d=Es_vqsdtlYssgAF4A3XSWnRVXoRhHI0Nw5kbnX4TQidZ-ER24J-iO0awsG5JH1rtQZR_iEqhZs7sdOBQ9bRTWyylEaGjH7fv-s8DBZ9g2dBrQRgBCGkgUkMcfnp1eLLpQ46PuRCK6kw9bzcz5Laedpe2sZMPd6VRGBt-E7Jq3Hi6WSFYwQmlvlft0Bho70p20&t=7b689585
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'AbbreviatedMonthNames' of undefined or null reference
```

How can I disable entry into the textbox via keyboard and only allow entry by the `calendarextender`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add attribute `onkeydown="return false;"` to the textbox. This way user won't be able to type anything in, but the click will still work.

You may also want to add `onpaste ="return false;"` to prevent copy/pasting text.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to flag a couple stupid comments for ridiculous input. This worked very well. Why is it these options are not in Visual Studio's IntelliTrace?

Comment: @gh0st these are actually attributes of an HTML `input` element and not properties of ASP.NET TextBox control, this is why Visual Studio's Intellisense doesn't know them. But ASP.NET TextBox renders as input element in the browser, this is why this works. If you look at the page source you will see something like `<input type="text" onkeydown="return false;"...`

Comment: An added benefit of this over `onkeypress="return false;"` is that `onkeydown="return false;"` also disables the delete and backspace key strokes.

Comment: Doesn't allow tab key to work.  If a blind user is tabbing through your form they will get stuck at this field. Great solution otherwise though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, add it during page load at your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtFrm.Attributes.Add("readonly", "true");
}
```

This will prevent typing and copy pasting input from user at once.